# Call to undefined function SegmentOnce() After upgrade from CI 2 to CI3

Tags: function, codeigniter, undefined, upgrade, helper

After upgrading my site from Codeigniter 2 to Codeigniter 3, i keep receiving this error:

> Message: Call to undefined function SegmentOnce()

The function SegmentOnce() is defined on helper (trunk_helper.php):

```
if ( ! function_exists('SegmentOnce'))
{       function SegmentOnce($s){

        $url = str_replace(ROOT_PATH,"",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        $pieces = explode("/",$url);
        if(isset($pieces[$s])) {
        $ret =  str_replace("id=","",$pieces[$s]);

        return CleanMe($ret);
        }
        else
        {
            return 'no_segment';
        }

    }
```

On my controller, the SegmentOnce() function is called:

```
define("QSTRING", $qstr);
        $langs = $this->config->item('my_lang');
        $get_lang_from_url = SegmentOnce(1 + ROOT_SEGMENT).'/';
        $current_lang_id = 0;
        $current_lang = '';




            foreach($langs as $val) {
                if($get_lang_from_url == $val['name'].'/'){
                    $current_lang_id = $val['id'];
                    $current_lang = $val['name'];


                        $lngth = strlen($val['name']);

                        $qstr = substr($qstr, $lngth);


                    if(substr($qstr ,0, 1) == '/' ) {
                        $qstr = substr($qstr , 1);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Helpers are loaded in the beginning of the controller:

```
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->helper('text');
    $this->load->helper('string');
```

I tried loading helpers from autoload.php, still the same issue.

> INFO - 2019-01-16 14:25:05 --> Config Class Initialized  INFO -
>
> 2019-01-16 14:25:05 --> Hooks Class Initialized  DEBUG - 2019-01-16
>
> 14:25:05 --> UTF-8 Support Enabled  INFO - 2019-01-16 14:25:05 -->
>
> Utf8 Class Initialized  INFO - 2019-01-16 14:25:05 --> URI Class
>
> Initialized  DEBUG - 2019-01-16 14:25:05 --> No URI present. Default
>
> controller set.  INFO - 2019-01-16 14:25:05 --> Router Class
>
> Initialized  INFO - 2019-01-16 14:25:05 --> Output Class Initialized
>
> INFO - 2019-01-16 14:25:05 --> Security Class Initialized  DEBUG -
>
> 2019-01-16 14:25:05 --> Global POST, GET and COOKIE data sanitized
>
> INFO - 2019-01-16 14:25:05 --> Input Class Initialized  INFO -
>
> 2019-01-16 14:25:05 --> Language Class Initialized  INFO - 2019-01-16
>
> 14:25:05 --> Loader Class Initialized  INFO - 2019-01-16 14:25:05 -->
>
> Controller Class Initialized  INFO - 2019-01-16 14:25:05 --> Helper
>
> loaded: url_helper  INFO - 2019-01-16 14:25:05 --> Helper loaded:
>
> text_helper  INFO - 2019-01-16 14:25:05 --> Helper loaded:
>
> string_helper  ERROR - 2019-01-16 14:25:05 --> Severity: error -->
>
> Exception: Call to undefined function SegmentOnce()
>
> C:\xampp\htdocs\application\controllers\Trunk_Controller.php 54'

The older CI2 was based on PHP5.6. This issue happened on PHP5.6 and also on PHP7.3 (running now).

I am using Xampp for windows.

Note*: I am quite new to PHP and MVC.

Thanks.

Comment: Seems, you don't load trunk_helper

Comment: I tried loading the helper on the top of the page, it adds me another error. I also tried loading it on autoload.php, again adds me another error. I think the helper is loaded already, but somehow the controller fails to read the specific function.  And as i mentioned, it works perfectly on Codeigniter 2.

Comment: What an error have you got after adding helper loading?